# Error with libomp while running lightgbm -- image not found

Tags: python, lightgbm

Getting the following error on Mac (M1 chip) while running lightgbm model:

```
OSError: dlopen(/Users/makhmood/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/podder-task-base-jxeZcfn9-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/lightgbm/lib_lightgbm.so, 6): Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/libomp/lib/libomp.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/makhmood/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/podder-task-base-jxeZcfn9-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/lightgbm/lib_lightgbm.so
  Reason: image not found
```

Tried a lot of things, such as symlinks and reinstalling everything, but doesn't work anyways. How it can be solved and why does it crashes?

Comment: Actually, I have installed libomp with brew. I'm working from conda environment and  running poetry environment above it